# Index Error while applying a function to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, index-error

I am trying to calculate the weighted average. I have a data frame new_df with item, rating count ( called Rating), rating mean. I have defined a function for weighted average. Now when I try to add a column to this data frame and apply the weighted average function to it I get an index error.

Dataframe shape
(1005247, 2)

Code

```
m=ratingcount_itemid['Rating'].quantile(0.90)
C=new_df['Rating_Mean'].mean()
# WEIGHTED AVERAGE 
def weighted_rating(X, m=m, C=C):
    V=X[new_df['Rating']]
    R=X[new_df['Rating_Mean']]
    return (V/(V+m)*R) + (m/(m+V)*C)
new_df['score']=new_df.apply(weighted_rating,axis=1)
```

Error - IndexError: index 14 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including the input and the full error traceback. You can [edit] the question. Se [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Pandas so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you :)